# prestashop: let prestashop creates https links

Tags: php, https, smarty, prestashop

Good day all.
I have a custom theme in Prestashop 1.6, at a certain moment, into the footer of the page, some links were created:

```
href="{$link->getCategoryLink($smarty.get.id_category, null, $lang.id_lang,null,null )}"
```

the whole site is running under SSL, but the links are returned as "http://...."

is there a way to force Prestashop to create ONLY https links?
else, is smarty capable to make a "search and replace" in that string? I mean, if I can't make it create in the proper way, I could change the link after is been created...

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `getCategoryLink` method of `Link` class, there called `protected function getBaseLink($id_shop = null, $ssl = null)` without second parameter.

And in `getBaseLink` you should see:

```
if ($ssl === null)
{
    if ($force_ssl === null)
    $force_ssl = (Configuration::get('PS_SSL_ENABLED') && Configuration::get('PS_SSL_ENABLED_EVERYWHERE'));
    $ssl = $force_ssl;
}
```

so, to get ssl links, you need, in backoffice, enable SSL for whole shop (there is an option), by default it's enabled for cart/order process only.
OR build url manually OR override e.g. getBaseLink method and set $ssl = true

Comment: well, the SSL "should" be already activate for the whole shop (but I'll ask to check for this for sure), it should be a matter of .htacces which is not been "updated" to the SSL rules? is that possible? and in that case, it should be only a matter of refreshing the .htaccs

Comment: hm, in this case, and I hope you already cleared all caches, try to debug what is return `getBaseLink` method, especially value of `$force_ssl` static property, I see no reasons for this behavior. There is no overrides for Link class?